# Does Qiskit Statevector has actual speed up for Grover Search?

Tags: programming, qiskit, grovers-algorithm, quantum-circuit

From [Qiskit document](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.algorithms.Grover.html?highlight=grover#qiskit.aqua.algorithms.Grover), the [Statevector](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector.html?highlight=statevector#qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector) can be used to specify the oracle of Grover Search. After seeing the [source code](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/quantum_info/states/statevector.html#Statevector) of the operators, it seems a statevector is converted to a rank-1 projector operator. In this case, the operator may not be unitary.

The code below can be run on a real IBMQ machine.

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import Grover
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

oracle = Statevector([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0])
good_state = ['110','101']
grover = Grover(oracle=oracle, good_state=good_state)
# backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_lima')
backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
result = grover.run(quantum_instance=backend)
print('Result type:', type(result))
print()
print('Success!' if result.oracle_evaluation else 'Failure!')
print('Top measurement:', result)
```

However, it does not make sense to me because the operator here is not unitary.
[image]

I am wondering if Statevector of Qiskit has actual speed up or it is just for illustration of Grover Search. Besides, how does it realize when the operator is not unitary?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question! In future, please copy and paste code rather than posting screenshots, as it makes it easier for other people to run it if they want/need to

Comment: Yes, I have edited the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that the actual oracle used in the algorithm is not obtained from `oracle.to_operator()`. If you look up [the code](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/amplitude_amplifiers/grover.html#Grover) for Grover's algorithm, you can see the following:

```
grover_operator = GroverOperator(oracle=oracle,
                                 state_preparation=state_preparation,
                                 reflection_qubits=reflection_qubits,
                                 mcx_mode=mct_mode)
```

Then, you can take a look at the [`GroverOperator` source code](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/circuit/library/grover_operator.py#L183) to find the following:

```
if isinstance(oracle, Statevector):
    from qiskit.circuit.library import Diagonal  # pylint: disable=cyclic-import
    oracle = Diagonal((-1) ** oracle.data)
```

What this does is explained in the documentation: it builds a diagonal matrix whose entries on the diagonal are all equal to $(-1)^{x_i}$, where the $x_i$ are the entries of your `Statevector`. In your case, those entries on the diagonal will all be equal to $1$ except for the ones corresponding to the states $|101\rangle$ and $|110\rangle$ which will be equal to $-1$. You can easily see that:

1. This operator is unitary
2. This operator flips the good states as it is supposed to

Since it is used for initialiazing the Grover's algorithm, I don't think it has any kind of speedup when compared to more "traditional" initialisation methods.

Comment: Adding to this very good answer: Using the full statevector to construct the oracle would invalidate any quantum speedup since you need an exponential amount of data to represent the oracle.

Comment: It makes sense to me. Thanks